# Regarding Schubert's Missing 'Gastein' Symphony

Tags: history, musicology

My understanding has been that Schubert's 'Gastein Symphony' was presumed lost, until scholars realized it was in fact his 9th symphony (the 'Great'). But Wikipedia tells me the 7th Symphony, D. 729, is a structurally complete work. Is there then a symphony of Schubert's (i.e., of the nine) which doesn't actually exist?

Comment: Did you mean "Unfinished symphonies" instead of "Symphonies that doesn't exist" ?

Comment: No. My understanding is that Schubert wrote 7 ½ symphonies (seven completed symphonies and the two movements of the 'Unfinished'). I say this because the Gastein, which was thought to be lost, turned out to be identical with the 'Great' symphony, Schubert's last (excepting the drafts for a tenth). But you can find performances of D. 729 on YouTube. So... ?

Comment: Is this a better fit for Music Fans? I'm not sure it's about music practice or theory, more about music history.

Comment: @IsaacYangHaoTung The so-called "unfinished symphony" is D.759, not D.729. But there are several "genuinely unfinished" Schubert symphonies, which created a historical muddle over the numbering. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schubert's_symphonies.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is any *conclusive* evidence that Schubert ever wrote a symphony which is now completely lost.

But considering that he was a very prolific composer who left many works incomplete, and who died young with only about 100 of his 1500 known works actually published during his lifetime, there will probably never be a definitive answer to the question.